# Adding bar labels shrinks dodged bars in seaborn.objects

Tags: python, seaborn, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to add text labels to the top of a grouped/dodged bar plot using **seaborn.objects**.

Here is a basic dodged bar plot:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','b','b'],
                    'x':['1','2','1','2'],
                   'y':[3,4,1,2]})
   
(so.Plot(dat, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'group')
 .add(so.Bar(),so.Dodge()))
```

[image: A dodged bar plot]

I can add text labels to the top of a non-dodged bar plot using `so.Text()`, no problem.

```py
(so.Plot(dat.query('group == "a"'), x = 'x', y = 'y', text = 'group')
 .add(so.Bar())
 .add(so.Text({'va':'bottom'})))
```

[image: A text-labeled bar plot]

However, when I combine dodging with text, the bars shrink and move far apart.

```py
(so.Plot(dat.query('group == "a"'), x = 'x', y = 'y', text = 'group')
 .add(so.Bar())
 .add(so.Text({'va':'bottom'})))
```

[image: Dodged barplot with text labels that looks bad]

This looks worse the more categories there are - in my actual application the bars have thinned out to single lines.

Setting the `gap` parameter of `so.Dodge()` or the `width` parameter of `so.Bar()` doesn't seem to be capable of solving the problem (although either will alleviate it slightly if I'm not too picky).

I'm guessing that the bar plot is using the `so.Dodge()` settings appropriate for text in order to figure out its own dodging, but that doesn't seem to be working right. Note that reversing the order I `.add()` the geometries doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [isn't](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2981) [ideal](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2982) but can be worked around by assigning `text` only in the layer with the Text (or un-assigning it from the Bar layer) and restricting the variables used to compute the text dodge:

```
(
    so.Plot(dat, x='x', y='y', color='group')
    .add(so.Bar(), so.Dodge())
    .add(so.Text({'va':'bottom'}), so.Dodge(by=["color"]),  text='group')
)
```

[image]